# Rails-api: Parameters ignored and new record created with Null values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I am building a restful Rails API using the rails-api package and I can't seem to get a simple CREATE to work with POST because the parameters being passed in are not included in the INSERT statement. I can create records from the rails console. I've checked every obvious cause and couldn't resolve the issue - some help by the community would be appreciated. Relevant code below along with test case and log files.

**routes.rb**

```
MyApp::Application.routes.draw do
    resources :people, except: [:new, :edit]
end
```

**people_controller.rb**

```
class PeopleController < ApplicationController
#POST/people
#POST/people.json
def create
    @person = Person.new(params[:person])

    if @person.save
        render json: @person, status: :created location: @person
    else
        render json: @person.erros, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
end
```

**Model: person.rb**

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

**wrap_parameters.rb**
*This will allow clients to submit POST requests without having to specify any root elements. This is currently configured but the code doesn't work without it either...*

```
ActiveSupport.on_load(:action_controller) do
    wrap_parameters format: [:json] if respond_to?(:wrap_parameters) end
```

**Run test in local Windows environment using Curl via Git Bash**

Initialize local rails server: rails s, open GIT Bash and execute CURL command below:

```
Curl -X POST -H "Content-TYPE: application/json" -d '{"first_name":"Michael", "last_name":"Foo", "email_address":"test", "password":"Foobar44"}' http://localhost:3000/people
```

**Curl response output:**

```
{"id":9,"created_at":"2014-02-28T18:57:53.283z", "updated_at":"2014-02-28T18:57:53.283z","first_name":null,"last_name":null,"email_address":null, "password":null}
```

**WEBrick Log output**

```
Started POST "/people" for 127.0.0.1
ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load [SELECT "schema_migrations".*FROM "schema_migrations"]
Processing by PeopleController#create as */*
Parameters: {"first_name"=>"Michael", "last_name"=>"Foo", "email_address"=>"test", "password"=>"Foobar44"}
[INSERT INTO "people" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2)
RETURNING ...
Completed 201 Created in 55ms
```

Comment: I'm guessing that this has to do with wrap_parameters not being called.  As a sanity check can you inspect the params hash in the create action and see what the output is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using strong parameters (default behavior for rails 4)

In your controller try it:

`@person = Person.new(person_params)`

and then add a protected method in the same controller

```
protected
def person_params
  params.require(:person).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email_address, :password)
end
```

Comment: I hope they update the rails-api generators to comply with rails 4. Thanks again!!

Answer (score 0):

**ISSUED RESOLVED: Sergey K., resolved my question via Odesk.**

Are you using rails 4 for your project? Because in rails 4 you can't do

Person.create(params[:person])

as it will raise ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributes exception.

You'll need to create private method and explicitly tell rails what attributes you permit and require:

private
    def person_params
      params.required(:person).permit(:name, :age)
    end

and then do:

Person.create(person_params)

You can read more about strong_parameters and mass assignment protection here:
https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters